# Caching on entity's property and dependency to third party on a getter

Tags: php, caching, dependencies, entity, domain-driven-design

I have an implementation problem that I don't find the best solution to resolve it.

I have a simple entity :

```
<?php

class Game
{
    // array
    private $statistics;

    // Datetime
    private $ended;

    ...

    public function isEnded()
    {
        return new Datetime >= $this->ended;
    }

    public function getStatistics($service)
    {
        if ($this->isEnded()) {
            return $this->statistics;
        }

        // The third party service will compute fresh statistics
        // and refresh the Game's property
        $service->computeStatistics($this);

        return $this->statistics;
    }
}
```

I want to store definitively the game's statistics in its private property `statistics` when the game is ended. But as you can see, if the game isn't finished I must compute statistics to have fresh data. To do so, I use a third service given to `Game::getStatistics()` to make the job.

As I know that an entity must not have dependencies, even more on a getter, what is the best solution to apply this caching behavior on a private property ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your calculations of statistics depends only on the data of the Game object itself, just move the `computeStatistics` method on Game.

If `computeStatistics` uses data from elsewhere as well, than use the double dispatch pattern : http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/

This is almost what you are doing already, you have a domain service that will do the calculation, the only thing I'd do differently is make `$service->computeStatistics($this);` side effect free like so:

```
$statistics = $service->computeStatistics($this);
```

In this way, your entity does not depend on implementation, it depends on an abstraction, that is, it needs a service who has a method `computeStatistics` that takes a Game and returns a statistics. This domain service is a part of your domain model, just as Game is. So Game depends on your domain model, which is fine. Domain Model can depend on Domain Model.